# error validating matchExpression when using podAffinity and podAntiaffinity

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am trying to create a podAffinity for the replicas of my deployment to be deployed in different nodes within my GCP cluster, I have followed the documentation an this site https://thenewstack.io/implement-node-and-pod-affinity-anti-affinity-in-kubernetes-a-practical-example/ but I get this error when executing apply:

```
error: error validating ".\\K8s\\6flask-deployment.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution[0].labelSelector): unknown field "MatchExpressions" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector;
```

This is my flask-deployment.yaml. I have tried to set it also underneath the first spec but it does not work neither

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-deployment
  namespace: flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app
      deploy: separate
      run: together
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app
        deploy: separate
        run: together
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              MatchExpressions:
                - key: deploy
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - separate
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname  
      containers:
```

Is it an identation mistake? the kubernetes linter does not flag anything and I have been comparing with other examples here in SO and over the web and I cannot find the mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever key-value you specify in `matchExpressions` also needs to be in `labels` and `matchLabels` of the pod `spec` instead of `metadata` section.It should be as below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  namespace: flask-app
spec:
  replicas: 2  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deploy: separate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: separate
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: deploy
                operator: In
                values:
                - separate
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Comment: so does the matchExpressions need to be in both labels and matchLabels field?

Comment: I still get an error even doing so as you said I have updated it above with the current configuration and the output error

Comment: Use `matchExpressions` instead of `MatchExpressions`